# How to remove exception in jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I am getting this error while running the server jboss .can you please tell me why it occurring I don't do any thing in code .My code is running fine when I was using yesterday , But now it is showing error when I run the server ?

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/ejb/plugins/keygenerator/KeyGeneratorFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:45)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:689)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:275)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:90)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.ejb.plugins.keygenerator.KeyGeneratorFactory from BaseClassLoader@3dac34{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@f49347{name=vfsfile:/H:/setupfile/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/uuid-key-generator.sar/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@159ac93{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=java.net.URLClassLoader@166a22b} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@15802876[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4ob1o-hzhcae-hqoyfl62-1-hqoyfpsn-1m real=vfsmemory://5c4ob1o-hzhcae-hqoyfl62-1-hqoyfpsn-1m], FileHandler@15619593[path=uuid-key-generator.sar context=file:/H:/setupfile/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/H:/setupfile/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/uuid-key-generator.sar/]]  delegates=null exported=[org.jboss.ejb.plugins.keygenerator.uuid, META-INF, org.jboss.ejb.plugins.keygenerator.hilo] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)

    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractComponentDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractComponentDeployer.java:78)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1448)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1166)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1107)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:823)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:783)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:985)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:775)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:258)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:97)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:860)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception loading class for ScopeKey addition.
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.addBeanComponent(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.deploy(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:126)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.ejb.EJB2UserTransactionProvider from BaseClassLoader@9485d{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@16dd2b6{name=vfsfile:/H:/setupfile/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/ejb2-container-jboss-beans.xml domain=ClassLoaderDomain@159ac93{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=java.net.URLClassLoader@166a22b} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@19186445[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4ob1o-hzhcae-hqoyfl62-1-hqoyfpsn-1n real=vfsmemory://5c4ob1o-hzhcae-hqoyfl62-1-hqoyfpsn-1n]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.addBeanComponent(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:63)
    ... 35 more
14:52:39,588 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/H:/setupfile/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/ejb3-connectors-jboss-beans.xml state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: vfsfile:/H:/setupfile/jboss-6.0.0.M1/server/default/deploy/ejb3-connectors-jboss-beans.xml
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.deploy(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:136)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.deploy(AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.java:125)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.internalDeploy(AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.java:102)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractComponentDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractComponentDeployer.java:78)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1448)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1166)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1107)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1633)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:935)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1083)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please format the code in readable format :)\

Comment: And please dont use milestone build of AS6, try with 6.0.0.Final or even 6.1.0.Final, M1 is milestone one build, as in first alpha of AS6. Problems milestone/alpha builds are expected.